# WP plugin to change post category *multiple times* based on date

Tags: wordpress

You can use the Wordpress plugin [Post Expirator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/) to change post category one time on a certain date.

I want to use it for an art gallery which shows Upcoming Exhibitions, Current Exhibitions and Past Exhibitions. All posts (exhibitions) will start out as "upcoming," then change to "current" while the exhibitions is on, and then move into "Past" once it is over. So I need to change category *twice*.
This seems fairly simple and I'm surprised I haven't found an plugin.

PS It doesn't have to be free.

Comment: This isn't necessarily simple - it would require some sort of architecture to keep track of multiple changes per post rather than just one. Post Expirator has a feature requests forum; have you tried posting there?